# ng-disabled with function that trigger when change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a submit validation button that need to be enable when all fields is being entered correctly. As the validation is too complex and is not able to be solve by using formName.$invalid alone, i need to write a function to cater the validation. I expect that the shouldEnable function to be trigger for each of the model changes inside. But it does not. Os is there any alternative for this?

Initial

```
<button ng-disabled="formName.$invalid">Submit</button>
```

Expected

```
<button ng-disabled="shouldEnable()">Submit</button>

$scope.shouldEnable = function() {
    $scope.isEnable = true;
    angular.forEach($scope.form.input2, function(val) {
        if($scope.form.input2.inputA && $scope.form.input2.inputB) {
            isEnable = false;
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your function needs to return boolean value:

```
$scope.shouldEnable = function() {
    var isEnable = true;
    // make necessary checks
    return isEnable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular's data-binding, You should use something like this :

```
<button ng-disabled="shouldEnable">Submit</button>

// yourObject is the object you've map in the form
$scope.$watch('yourObject', function(newObject) {
   $scope.shouldEnable = isValid(newObject);
});
```